# django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: nouveaucontact.html

Tags: python, django

i'm Learning how to use Django and i have a problem… I Don't know why it tells me that my Template nouveaucontact.html doesnotExist… 
(I have put os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates') in my settings.py)
Thank you for your help :)

You can see my code:
blog\urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('accueil', views.accueil, name='accueil'),
    path('article/<int:id>-<slug:slug>', views.lire, name='lire'),
    path('article/<int:id_article>', views.view_article, name='afficher_article'),
    path('redirection', views.view_redirection, name='redirection'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('nouveaucontact/', views.nouveau_contact, name='nouveau_contact'),
    path('date', views.date_actuelle, name='date'),
    path('addition/<int:nombre1>/<int:nombre2>', views.addition, name='addition'),
    # autre manière d'écrire (d4 attend un nombre à 4 chiffres que la vue disposera sous le nom year
    re_path(r'^articles/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})', views.list_articles, name='afficher_liste_articles')
]
```

views.py

```
def nouveau_contact(request):
    sauvegarde = False
    form = NouveauContactForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES) #request.POST => pour els donnés textuelles et request.FILES pour les fichiers comme les photos
    if form.is_valid():
        contact = Contact()
        contact.nom = form.cleaned_data["nom"]
        contact.adresse = form.cleaned_data["adresse"]
        contact.photo = form.cleaned_data["photo"]
        contact.save()
        sauvegarde = True

    return render(request, 'nouveaucontact.html', {
        'form': form,
        'sauvegarde': sauvegarde
    })
```

forms.py

```
class NouveauContactForm(forms.Form):
    nom = forms.CharField()
    adresse = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    photo = forms.ImageField()
```

models.py

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    adresse = models.TextField()
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom
```

nouveaucontact.html

```
<h1>Ajouter un nouveau contact</h1>

{% if sauvegarde %}
    <p>Ce contact a bien été enregistré.</p>
{% endif %}

<p>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="."> <!-- # enctype ici permet au navigateur de pouvoir envoyer les fichiers au serveur web -->
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form.as_p }}
       <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</p>
```

[Here the yellow screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh9LI.jpg)

[Django tried loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6kly.png)

[the position of nouveaucontact.html in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxwiN.png)

Comment: Can you share the top portion of the yellow error screen you get when you try to go to the page while DEBUG=True? There is a section that tells you which directories your app looked in for template files.

Comment: i've put the Screenshot in a link (sorry i am novice on stackover flow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you that Django is looking for the template at `crepes_bretonnes\templates\nouveaucontact.html`, and `crepes_bretonnes\blog\templates\nouveaucontact.html` (and a couple of other places in the Django installation that you can ignore).

If you move the template to either of those places and restart runserver, then Django should find it.

If you use the `blog\templates` directory, then you don't need to set `'DIRS': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` in your `TEMPLATES` setting.

Comment: thank you @Alasdair, it works after i moved my Template :)